# How do I display Tool-tip on an excel column chart contained in a sheet that is protected(UserInterfaceOnly)?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, tooltip, gantt-chart

I have a stacked column chart with many series and with legend etc. I am having to display a tooltip when the mouse hovers over the series and the good thing is I achieved that using code from [Here](https://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2016/08/customizable-tooltips-on-excel-charts.html).
Only problem is I want the user not to delete the chart or move it. So I protect the sheet with

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Now since I have protected it the macro can make the chart active and still work with it but user cannot activate it. My tooltip program works only if user can activate the chart.
Here is a snap(Dummy)

[image: Tooltip shows on one of the series in Picture]

How do I keep the protection of the sheet as well as allow user to activate chart which displays the tooltip?

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure if this is possible. If you protect using `DrawingObjects = False`, the user will be able to activate the chart, but also edit and delete it...

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is possible (using Excel 365 and I think 2007 and newer):

1) Unlock Your worksheet.

2) Right click on Your chart and choose "Assign macro..." then assign the macro that is displaying tooltip for this chart.

3) Lock Your worksheet with disabling objects edition.

When You click on Your chart the assigned macro will fire (and display tooltip).
It is not possible to right click or edit the chart and You are able to display tooltip.

There are also events that can fire appropraite macro, e. g. to unprotect worksheet (on activate) and protect on deactivate. You can also catch when user tries to edit chart by using event on click and disabling it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/chart-object-events

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply... I will disable editing/protect the chart on click and reactivate or un-protect it on mouse move. Let us see if this fixes it. Will keep posting updates here...